# jQuery trigger and reverse .animate

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I was wondering how to do 2 things, first how to reverse animate the imgs and dialog box back (see what I mean in jfiddle!) and second how to trigger that reverse animation with the user click any where on the page BUT the white dialog box div.(Please see jfiddle the see what im talking about, click on top left img to see the animation) Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hBb9L/7/

Thank You For All The Future Help!

```
$("#e").click(function() {
  //done
$("#re").animate({
  "margin-top": "104px"
}, 800);
$("#ret").animate({
  "margin-top": "104px"
}, 800);
$(".popu").animate({
     "margin-top": "-102px"
 }, 800);
 $("#s").show(200);
 });
```

Comment: didn't have time to really work on this, but a quick and dirty workup:  http://jsfiddle.net/hBb9L/13/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set all the css values to 0px!